# ImageView not scroll along RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have two views in my NestedScrollView one is my separate imageview and second is recyclerview showing list of images. Now the problem is recyclerview images scrolls but my seprate imageview stays on its position. I want my separate imageview to scroll along recyclerview images.

I have **tried** many solutions like in some stackoverflow posts users suggest to use setNestedScrollingEnabled(False) property but it not works. I worked on it for many days but no solution works. I will be so glad if someone assist me!

My XML File:

```
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sadboy" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postRV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My JAVA File:

```
   postRV = findViewById(R.id.postRV);
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));
    list.add(new StoryModel(R.drawable.girl));


    StoryAdapter storyAdapter = new StoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

    postRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    postRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    postRV.setAdapter(storyAdapter);
```

[my code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OPm8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Before setting nested scrolling enabled as false make sure you set that the recycler view has fixed size.

```
 postRV.setHasFixedSize(true); 
 postRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

This makes sure that the scrollview is aware of the actual height of the recycler view and scrolling is contained in the scroll view and not the recyclerView.

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postRV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Also the height of recycler view should be wrap_content and not match_parent. As the height needs to be measured after the items are added and needs to be contained inside the scrollview and not the screen.

Comment: tried but still same issue

Comment: I want my imageview should scroll horizontally with recyclerview please help me i am stuck here

Comment: Can you share your layout manager code. Which layout manager are you using? And the recycler view should scroll vertically and image should scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Try `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `NestedScrollView` and `RelativeLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`

Try below code to horizontal scroll image with recyclerview:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/aa_1" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/postRV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

This code work for me.